# FullCalendar will not save events

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar for an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  Upon activating dayclick, I have a bootstrap modal popup that asks for the event Title, Date, Time start, and event length.  It will create an event, but if I try to add another, it returns my else statement that I have provided in my "popup save" portion of my code.

Here is the dayclick function:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#eventTitle').val("");
        $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
        $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
        ShowEventPopup(date);
    },
```

Show popup:

```
function ShowEventPopup(date) {
    ClearPopupFormValues();
    $('#popupEventForm').modal('toggle');
    $('#eventTitle').focus();
}

function ClearPopupFormValues() {
    $('#eventID').val("");
    $('#eventTitle').val("");
    $('#eventDateTime').val("");
    $('#eventDuration').val("");
}
```

Popup save:

```
$('#btnPopupSave').click(function () {

$('#popupEventForm').hide();

var dataRow = {
    'Title': $('#eventTitle').val(),
    'NewEventDate': $('#eventDate').val(),
    'NewEventTime': $('#eventTime').val(),
    'NewEventDuration': $('#eventDuration').val()
};

ClearPopupFormValues();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Calendar/SaveEvent",
    data: dataRow,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response === 'True') {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            alert('New event saved!');
        }
        else {
            alert('Error, could not save event!');
        }
    }
});
});
```

Create new event (in CalendarEvent.cs model):

```
public static bool CreateNewEvent(string Title, string NewEventDate, string NewEventTime, string NewEventDuration)
    {
        try
        {
            StoreDbEntities ent = new StoreDbEntities();
            Calendar rec = new Calendar();
            rec.Title = Title;
            rec.DateTimeScheduled = DateTime.ParseExact(NewEventDate + " " + NewEventTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            rec.EventLength = Int32.Parse(NewEventDuration);
            ent.Calendars.Add(rec);
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Save event (in CalendarController.cs):

```
public bool SaveEvent(string Title, string NewEventDate, string NewEventTime, string NewEventDuration)
    {
        return CalendarEvent.CreateNewEvent(Title, NewEventDate, NewEventTime, NewEventDuration);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns false when an exception is thrown so something in the `try` block is messing up. I would guess the exception is being thrown when you try to parse the event date or event duration to an `int`. Or you could be trying to insert invalid data types to your context. Put a breakpoint at the `SaveChanges()` and run the application through the debugger to step through the code, or another obvious option is to look at the exception it gives you.

Comment: Inner exception states: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Calendars'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Calendars'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: That error is pretty straightforward.  You are trying to insert a new instance of Calendar but the primary key that you are trying to insert already exists.I assume that the ID field is the primary key. Look at the ID field of the calendar object just before you add it the context and compare to the existing ones in the database. And check to make sure the primary key is set right.

Comment: Ended up being that Identity specification was set to "No."  Changed it to "Yes" and it works now.  Thanks for all the help.  I really appreciate it!